# If a satellite performs an reentry, how does its speed vary?

Tags: acceleration, orbital-motion, drag, speed

If a satellite were to leave the Earth's orbit and perform a reentry with no parachutes or rockets to slow it down, how does its speed vary?

I know that from equations, as orbital radius decreases, speed should increase. However, there is also drag to be considered, which increases as speed increases. So if we were to graph the speed of the satellite during reentry with respect to time, would there be a time interval in which the satellite actually decelerates instead of accelerating?

Comment: This is how reentry works! At least if the satellite is manned

Comment: Think about this: if the Apollo capsules had not slowed down during reentry they would have been travelling at orbital velocity, or above, when they opened their parachutes, the parachutes would have failed immediately, and they would have hit the ocean at orbital velocity, or above.  That would not be a survivable event. It's the equivalent of about 80 tonnes of TNT going off, so it might well also not be survivable for the ships waiting to pick them up, depending on how close they were.